# Flutter: Navigate to new screen display as a Modal

Tags: flutter, react-native, mobile, navigation

Example (React Native Navigation):

[React Native Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvdd0.gif)

How to navigate to new screen as a Modal like this using Flutter?

React Native Navigation Docs: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/modal/

I'm trying to use `fullscreenDialog: true` but not working, I can't drag screen.

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => SectionCRoute(), 
  fullscreenDialog: true),
);
```

Expect: minimize the back screen and drag modal screen.

Edit: Is there any way to use `Navigator`, not  `showModalBottomSheet`.

Comment: Hey zmix, would you mind sharing a code, what you have tried so far? Meanwhile do try using `showModalBottomSheet` as Kami answered, that should work for you as per your requirment.

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana  I have added the code above

Answer (score 1):

you should use the showBottomModalSheet function.

try this:

```
  ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                      context: context, builder: (context)
                  =>
                  Container( height: 900, color: Colors.blue,)); // also can set height to 0.9 of screen
                },
                child: const Text('Open Modal'),
              ),
```

Comment: Thanks Kami Tzayig, But Is there any way to use `Navigation route`, not `showModalBottomSheet`.